# Benefits/Disadvantages .NET Forms 1 Page static Website of Having 30+ Nested User Controls?

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms

I am new to .NET 4.5 but if a forms based websites has one master page for the 1 aspx page (of a 1 page website) and every little static part is in its own user control, sometimes nested one inside the other 4 layers deep, what exactly is the benefit of such a structure over keeping the main section in the aspx file while having the header + footer in the master file?

It seems an excruciating headache to go to each user control (which is static in itself containing just the html, js, css used only by that mini section within the user control - a slider for example) rather than having it all together since its static anyhow?

The senior developer says that the structure is how things are done in .NET, but I am from a php background so am failing to see the wisdom here.

Please help me see what my brain refused to accept.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic], try re-tagging as [tag:asp.net].

Comment: Sorry about that. Had I known asp 3.0 would be around 14 years after MS proclaimed its death when .NET was born, life would have been easier.

Comment: I think the answer is going to be "depends". In some cases the separation of controls will allow a lot of flexibility (like @KHeaney suggests). In other cases depending on the size of the components / controls it adds needless complexity like you're mentioning. It will be hard for anyone here to give you a concrete answer if it's "the right solution for you"(TM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slider is actually an excellent example for this. Imagine you decide to customize your slider so that it uses a Clorox Bleach bottle as the point icon. Now you want that slider to be used on survey.aspx when you are doing surveys about Clorox products. Imagine all the code that would now have to flood the survey page with just to deal with that one control when you can instead use an asp tag like

```
<uc:cloroxslider>.
```

Or imagine needing to add it to another page and then needing to edit that static control across the site because you decided the slider should be 1-10 now instead of 1-5. The point of user controls is to hold static items like that for simple editing and re-usability.

I will admit though that I do see it a bit uncommon to nest user controls as much as you are implying. User controls are best when they are designed in a way that that they can reasonably be called by multiple pages. I would think that they way your group is using them is likely a bit too granular if they cannot actually be reused in any fashion outside the parent user control or page.

**Edit:** added more information

see here for more discussion on the encapsulation benefits

[ASP.NET ascx vs. aspx - Do you reuse user controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283427/asp-net-ascx-vs-aspx-do-you-reuse-user-controls)

Also, while I don't know much about this, you can also do some stuff creating custom redistributal controls see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx

Comment: Yeh I agree with you if there was more than 1 page to the website. But the amount of time it takes to figure out which nested file some piece of the page is located in needlessly just bugs me. I thought there was some advantage beside encapsulation that I am missing. So then if a part of the page will never be reused again anywhere , does it make sense to have it in a user control?

Comment: encapsulation is the big one. To a certain extent there is also readability. While digging across those files may be a pain digging though a single 100,000 line file in my opinion is always worse. also edited my question a bit.